# Core Data model design for one entity with different meanings

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a server API that returns me the same Item object, under 3 different endpoints:

- /new/
- /recommended/
- /library/

The same Item could appear in both new and recommended lists.

I need to somehow track which items come from which endpoints, to show them as 3 different screens, while maintaing one big pool of items in database. What would be a good model for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some ultra normalization, but if you think that these are the only three classifications, you could just add them as boolean fields of your entity and mark each field as checked depending on which endpoint it came from. Here are some steps:

1. Download items from each end point
2. Lookup each item in Core Data by the entity's server ID. If the entity doesn't already exist in Core Data, create it
3. Set the entity fields with what you got from the server record
4. If it came from the "new" endpoint, set the "new" boolean field to YES. If from "recommended", set "recommended" boolean field to YES, etc.
5. Save the entity
6. When you perform your fetch in each of your views, just set your predicate to something like one of these:

   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"new = 1"];

   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recommended = 1"];

Comment: Thanks. What's the idea of normalization?

Comment: To normalize, you create another entity called something like "categories" and add a new row for each one--in your case "new", "recommended", or "library". Then, in the future, you could add others, say if you had yet another end point like "featured", for example. You then create a relationship in Core Data between your main entity and this category entity. The relationship would be many-to-many since you want one record per item. It would act as a grouping mechanism. Normalization is overkill if your categories are static, however, it makes sense to normalize them if they might change.